# Install opencv with Anaconda for python 3.4 on ubuntu

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu, machine-learning, anaconda

So the question is in question and might be already answered, but I haven't found a good answer.

I use latest ubuntu 15.04 and latest anaconda with python 3.4. I want to add opencv into it (to later install caffe). To do so I used this:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenCV

Just copied the script from answer and executed it. Seems like it have completed successfully, but when I open Spyder from anaconda and do

```
import cv2
```

I get a error that no such module is found. What am I doing wrong?

BTW, when I do

```
conda install opencv
```

I get the info that package opencv conflicts with package python 3.4(!!!)

Is there any good tutorial on full install of opencv for anaconda + python 3.4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I followed the instructions given at https://scivision.co/anaconda-python-opencv3/ This worked for me

Comment: Worked nicely. Thank you!